# How to use Link to replace rather than append to the URL in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a navigation bar:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <NavLink to="home">Home</NavLink>
  </span>
  <span>
    <NavLink to="find">Find</NavLink>
  </span>
</div>

<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/find" element={<Find />} />
</Routes>
```

Inside of home Component I am trying to do this:

```
<button>
  <Link to="find">
    Find
  </Link>
</button>
```

But the problem is whenever I click on **Find** in url it passes `"home/find"` but I don't want to push this route like this I want it to be just `"/find"`

Current output: localhost:3000/home/find
Expected output: localhost:3000/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing the `/`

```
<Link to="/find">
```

Comment: What if I want to push like I want to home/find

Comment: to="/home/find"